# Do you need to use API key for google maps API for client-side applications?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

They allow only 2,500 requests per key, so I must use client-side and use user's IP for requests. Do I need to use API key for google maps API for client-side applications? What if I don't and they found out? Would my domain get banned?

Comment: I don't know if you need to use the key in a client-side app. I suggest reading about [Map's API Licensing](https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing) and its [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms). If you don't follow it they **will** find out, and yes, your domain will be banned from ever acessing anything from Google.

Comment: which api version you ask about? You should add more specific tag google-maps-api-3 (if you ask about version 3).

Comment: @Tomas Version 3 (I think version 2 is depreciated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your first question, no you do not need a key on the client-side if you expect your application to make less than 25,000 [map loads](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) per day. If you don't have a key, and you reach the limit for 90 consecutive days - they will contact you about it and ask you to purchase a license (not shut their services down from your site). For more info read [Usage Limits and Billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) from the API docs.

Comment: Thanks, but how do they detect map loads if it's loaded with JavaScript? Or they see "referrer" in requests?

Comment: I'm not actually sure how they monitor that, my guess is they probably track your domain from the request headers when you make a request to google's service.

Comment: A ["map load" for javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) is a load of the API script.